# Selenium click CSS elmenents that have same class name

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to click the second element where "class=uiComposerAttachment photoAttachment"

[image: Selnium IDE for Firefox]

Comment: There's multiple elements with "class=uiComposerAttachment photoAttachment", I'm trying to click the second one.

Comment: There are multiple ways to access elements in Selenium. Some of them are using XPath, id, cssSelector etc, have you tried them all?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can't manage to click it. This is the closest I've got.

Comment: Are you sure XPath is not solving your issue? This is really strange. Maybe get your xpath manually and add it to your selenium test file.

Comment: Okay I think I see your problem now. You might have to wait ie verify till the button load up and then you click that button.

Answer (score 2):

Something different from XPath, is using the `nth-child` locator in CSS. Note this isn't supported in IE8 and below, but other modern browsers will be fine. Example to get the 2nd element:

```
css=*.uiComposerAttachment:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the Xpath of the class and use the Xpath then try.

```
   click | //*[@class='uiComposerAttachment photoAttachment']
```

Use this in the selenium IDE

Can you provide snapshot, how you find the Xpath of the class

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//*[@class='uiComposerAttachment photoAttachment'][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple elements with same xpath you can try below format of xpath to click the desired element.

As per your application, you have 2 elements with same xpath. So you can use the below xpath to click on the second element.

xpath=(//select[@name='listPartition'])[position()=2]

Answer (score 0):

As class is same, you need to identify element as per position.
This is second element that you mentioned, so you can use

```
xpath=(//*[@class="uiComposerAttachment photoAttachment"])[2]
```